# How to fetch value from a json response which is in array format in karate

Tags: dsl, karate

I am trying to fetch a value from my response which comes in a JSONArray format. I want to fetch the Id from the first array object.

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "next": "",
  "previous": "",
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "f78bde61-056a-4358-bbac-50bf524c965c",
      "name": "Auto_Approval",
      "description": "Lambda Functions Demo",
      "context": "hjk",
      "version": "v1",
      "provider": "hk",
      "status": "PUBLISHED",
      "thumbnailUri": null
    },
    {
      "id": "f78bde61-056a-4358-bbac-50bf524c965c",
      "name": "Auto_Approval",
      "description": "Lambda Functions Demo",
      "context": "knkl",
      "version": "v1",
      "provider": "uygi",
      "status": "PUBLISHED",
      "thumbnailUri": null
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "total": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 25
  }
}
```

I want to fetch the value of id.

I tried `response.list[0].id` but this is not working.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your JSON, a comma is missing. Kindly be more careful in future.

Paste the below and see it work.

```
* def response = 
"""
{
   "count":1,
   "next":"",
   "previous":"",
   "list":[
      {
         "id":"f78bde61-056a-4358-bbac-50bf524c965c",
         "name":"Auto_Approval",
         "description":"Lambda Functions Demo",
         "context":"hjk",
         "version":"v1",
         "provider":"hk",
         "status":"PUBLISHED",
         "thumbnailUri":null
      },
      {
         "id":"f78bde61-056a-4358-bbac-50bf524c965c",
         "name":"Auto_Approval",
         "description":"Lambda Functions Demo",
         "context":"knkl",
         "version":"v1",
         "provider":"uygi",
         "status":"PUBLISHED",
         "thumbnailUri":null
      }
   ],
   "pagination":{
      "total":1,
      "offset":0,
      "limit":25
   }
}
"""
* def id = response.list[0].id
* match id == 'f78bde61-056a-4358-bbac-50bf524c965c'
```

Comment: Even with this , i am still not able to fetch the Id.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: response.list[0].id, Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: @SnehaShukla lol ok. the time has come for me to refer you to this page. all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: my bad again. It was an issue with th e gateway timings.